# DIVs not nesting properly?

Tags: html, nested

On this page,

http://lumn.net/index.shtml

I'm having some problem with my DIVs that I can't explain (or find).  "blog" is supposed to nest inside "focal."  As a result, "focal" is supposed to stretch to the height of "blog" and push the blue bar to the bottom.  "focal," however, is running short, apparently defaulting to its minimum height of 440px, even though "blog" is substantially taller.

It lays out fine on my other pages.  I know people prefer to have questions include code, but I'm not even sure whether the problem is in my css or my html.  1000 thanks if you can help me figure this out.  I'm sure it's simple, but I'm not seeing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try placing this right before "focus" closing tag:

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

On your "blue footer" div use the following CSS:

```
clear: left;
```

This CSS specifies which sides of an element where other floating elements are not allowed.